# Function balanceOf is not constant issues

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, web3j, smart-contract-wallets, ruby

when i am trying to get erc20 balance of an address from smart contract getting balanceOf is not constant issue.

**myContractInstance.balanceOf("0x2cdfa0382bc9c43bdf645baf14d90aecc8a6ce5a")**

Getting this issue.

RuntimeError: Function balanceOf is not constant: balanceOf, requires to sign transaction

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which language/library are you using? Can you provide the whole script to test?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite some information missing to properly answer this question:

- What framework do you use and what programming languate?
- How do you create the `myContractInstance` (e.g. what ABI, is there a provider or signer)?

Making some assumptions I would say the following:
In the ABI that you use to create your contract instance the `balanceOf` method is not marked as `view`. Most libraries therefore will try to invoke a transaction to trigger a state change, which needs to be signed (to pay the transaction fee). But you probably did not provide a signer, therefore your library is throwing an error.

If the above is the case you can adjust the ABI so that the `balanceOf` method is marked as view. Or check if the web3 framework you use allows you do force a "call" instead of a transaction (e.g. `callStatic` with [Ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic))